# Flickering shadows in games. Help Please

Tags: technical-issues, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce-experience

Hello I would like to ask if there is a way to fix this flickering shadow. It appears in almost game that I'm playing. It's very weird.

My Rig:

Ryzen 3 3100

GT 1030 GDDR5

B450m mortar

8GB DDR4 RAM

720p Monitor

Here's what it looks like in game.

It's on the max setting.

I tried different game like GTA V (HIGH Settings) and I see those kind of shadow as well.

The Nvidia Control Panel is set to default as well.

Comment: Have you tried not having everything on the max setting, and see which option causes it?

Comment: The shadow it self is the one causing it. I tried leaving everything off except the shadow but it still does it

Comment: Is this shadow problem only in Dota or it also does it in other source games? Because if its the small flicker we see on the shadow, it just might be a bug in how that scene is lit in Source and not something actually with your setup.

Comment: Except that: all drivers are updated to their latest?

Comment: Yes. The driver version is 466.77 that came out just the other day

Comment: And I do notice it in GTA V as well. Shadow on my character in dark area becomes like that